# delete objects inParse after a set amount of time from a specific class

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

Hello I have an app that would upload photo's to the sever. Parse only gives us 20gb for storage and so I don't want to go over that limit. I want the server so that it would delete the files if it is 3 days old.  So this is the code

```
Parse.Cloud.job('deleteOldPosts', function(request, status) {
// All access
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

var today = new Date();
var days = 10;
var time = (days * 24 * 3600 * 1000);
var expirationDate = new Date(today.getTime() - (time));

var query = new Parse.Query('post');
    query.lessThan('createdAt', expirationDate);

    query.find().then(function (posts) {
        Parse.Object.destroyAll(posts, {
            success: function() {
                status.success('All posts are removed.');
            },
            error: function(error) {
                status.error('Error, posts are not removed.');
            }
        });
    }, function (error) {});

});
```

However If I use this code it would delete files from all classes. I just want this code to work on only one class. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: What is 3 days years?

Comment: Also, while Making your query, use query with classname.

Comment: Thank you for commenting first I don't get your comment "What is 3 days years? "

Comment: Is `post` the name of the class which contains the media files you wish to delete?

Comment: Your question says "3 days years old". I asked what do you mean by it? 3 days old? or three years old? By that I will be able to understand the `var time`

Comment: Yes. If I run the above code it will delete from all of the classes. I am having trouble making it delete only from a class named "post"

Comment: I am very sorry I looked at it sorry for the typo

Comment: Your query and delete only works on the `post` class. If other classes are being deleted you have something else doing it. Note also that this won't delete files associated with those objects you're deleting...

Comment: OK so this code var query = new Parse.Query('post'); Restricts it to post class?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this code at least. I think you found it [here] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21912727/delete-all-old-objects-in-parse-com)

Comment: Yes it makes the query to point to one specific class. Which is post.

Comment: Ok thank you I may have done something wrong with the others, Appreciate your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When deleting objects in cloud code, use `query.each` instead of `query.find` to ensure that you delete all objects matching the query .

`find` has the query limitation of 100 objects returned by default (or up to 1000 if `limit` is used). [Source](https://parse.com/questions/background-job-remove-all-objects-for-user)

Below is your updated code using a promise chain which calls `destroy` on each `Post` object. When *all* of the destroy promises have completed, the success status will be reached, and if *any* of the destroys fail then the error status will be reached.

```
Parse.Cloud.job('deleteOldPosts', function(request, status) {
    // All access
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

    var today = new Date();
    var days = 10;
    var time = (days * 24 * 3600 * 1000);
    var expirationDate = new Date(today.getTime() - (time));

    var query = new Parse.Query('post');
    query.lessThan('createdAt', expirationDate);
    query.each(function(post) {
        return post.destroy();
    }).then(function() {
        console.log("Delete job completed.");
        status.success("Delete job completed.");
    }, function(error) {
        alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        status.error("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    });
});
```